# Firebase rules for collection group subcollection: resource.data is empty?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I use collection grouped subcollections, so (in my understanding) I have to use a wildcard:

```
match /{path=**}/actions/{action} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

This is working so far.
It'sworking also when implenting another rule:

```
match /{path=**}/actions/{action} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null
                           && request.auth.token.email !='';
}
```

But I want to check if the user has access with data in the document and there comes the problem:

```
match /{path=**}/actions/{action} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null
                           && request.auth.token.email in resource.data.access;
}
```

leads to

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

with:

```
this.afs.collectionGroup("actions", ref => 
  ref.where("owner.email", "==", user.email)
).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(take(1))
```

So far I couldn't find any further information about how to access data within a wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

The data of document being accessed is present in `resource` and not `request`. So the rule should be:

```
request.auth.token.email in resource.data.access;
```

Do note that here `resource` has data of the document in actions sub-collection (`/actions/{doc}`).

You can find more information about data validation in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation).

Comment: You're right, thanks, I tried sooo many variants... The error is still the same - I edited my question for the right code

Comment: @bastifix you should be using `request.auth.token.email in resource.data.owner.email` because the email is stored in a nested field `owner.email` and not in an array. If the rule is about anyone else accessing the document and you have their email any where in the document, then please share a screenshot of the document.

Comment: Do I've to create an index for the field I'm using in the resource.data? It's working now with the index and I try to understand why ;-)